# how to read a variable from an already deployed smartcontract without a predeclared getter function?

Tags: contract-design

i want to read a variable from an existing contract to my own contract using smart contracts. (not js)

i know there are methods to import smart contracts:

1. import './OtherContract.sol'
2. contract cont is OtherContract {}

but I'm thinking of there is any method that we can put a contract's address and call/read that contract's functions/variables from another contract?

for example (something like):

1. import address(0x...)
2. contract cont = address(0x...)

Answer (score 0):

i think i've found my answer but i ddnt test it yet.
...using interface and make an object from it and point it to the deployed contract's address.

should be something like:

```
interface deployedContract { 
       function a() external returns(uint);
}

contract myContract {
       deployedContract dContract = deployedContract(0x000...00);
       
       uint returnedUintFromDeployedContractFunction = dContract.a();
}
```

i think it should work.
but what if i want to just **read a parameter** from an already deployed contract, i mean **not to call a function**.

is there any ways to define parameters in interface?
or is there anything like get method to get value of a **parameter** of an already deployed smart contract?

Comment: what is the default deceleration of getter function made by solidity for every public variabales?
is it possible to declare that as an interface?

Comment: ask this in another question

Comment: i want to read a variable from an already deployed smart contract, from my smart contract.
the variable is public but has not any getter function, just has its default getter function that solidity makes automatically for every public variables.

Comment: how is this possible to call a default getter function of a variable inside another smart contract?

Comment: for example: when u import some smart contracts into yours and you declare its interface, you can call its functions by using ImportedContract.FunctionWantToCall()

Comment: but how is this possible to read variables from that ImportedContract without getter function in its interface?\

Comment: basically variables cant be declared in interface!

Comment: is there any hidden implementation of the default getter function which solidity makes for public variables? so we can use it in interface and then use it as the getter function for that public variable.

Comment: for more details, i'm trying to code an ERC1155 which its tokenId have to be generated based on a number that is on another smart contract.
i want to know how may my _mint function can read that variable, which is on an already deployed smart contract. that contract im trying to read this variable from has not any getter function for that variable.
well i know its possible to get it via js or something else, but i think its more decentralized and automated if my _mint function itself can read that variable every time upon calling.

Comment: is this possible to read variables from that ImportedContract without getter function in its interface -> yes it possible, you can add the function to the interface by yourself. I will try something later and give you an answer probably in 5 hours

Comment: if the contract has a varibale like this "address public test;" then the auto generated function is called "test()" and you can go to the interface  sol file and add a function "function test() external view returns(address);"

Comment: thanks for exact answers! appreciated!

Comment: just tried it on a simple remix code, looks working well, thanks!